# Call metatable methods inside metatable itself

Tags: lua, metatable

Is there a way to call metatable methods inside the metatable itself? For example

```
local t = {}
local mt = {
    __index = {
        dog = function() print("bark") end,
        sound = function() t:dog() end
 }
}

setmetatable(t,mt)

t:Sound()
```

raises this error:

*attempt to call method 'Sound' (a nil value)*

Answer (score 5):

because you don't have `Sound`. Only `sound`.